# PHP img alt attribute

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, alt

I want to include an image alt attribute using PHP.

I currently have the following code...

```
    <?php echo img(IMAGEPATH . 'logo.png'); ?>
```

How would I go about adding the alt attribute - "my awesome alt" - to this image using PHP so that when I go into view source I see something like this for the image?

```
    <img src="http://examplesite.com/img/logo.png" alt="my awesome alt"/>
```

I am using codeigniter.

Comment: being pedantic: it's an alt *attribute*, not an alt tag. IMG is the tag; ALT is an attribute.

Comment: The [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#img) explains this well.

Comment: Do we even LOOK at the documentation anymore or just come straight to stackoverflow and start posting questions?

Comment: how much do you want to bet he wont accept an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo img(array('src'=>'image/picture.jpg', 'alt'=> 'alt information')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
<?php echo img(IMAGEPATH . 'logo.png',array('alt'=> 'alt information')); ?>
```